# Sort array based on the order of another array with repeating items

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have two arrays - the one contains ordered IDs, the other is an array with models which have an ID property. Here is an example of the IDs array:

```
ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl
n50cavoOJeRkjoRj11j3 
TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7 
TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7 
TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7 
ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl 
mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b 
TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7 
Gc5lnHAKWm1OyeMkA9e7
n50cavoOJeRkjoRj11j3 
mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b 
mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b 
ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl 
X9WyrvEE253keNdlbVZc 
ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl
```

In order to do the sorting of the second array I do:

```
func sort(by ids: [String]) -> [Model] {
   return self.sorted{ ids.index(of: $0.id)! < ids.index(of: $1.id)! }
}

[Model].sort(by: idsArray)
```

This works just fine for arrays with unique items. But as you can see in my IDs array I have repeating ones. So the result of this call will result in this model IDs order:

```
ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl
ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl
ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl
ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl
n50cavoOJeRkjoRj11j3
n50cavoOJeRkjoRj11j3
TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7
TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7
TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7
TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7
mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b
mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b
mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b
Gc5lnHAKWm1OyeMkA9e7
X9WyrvEE253keNdlbVZc
```

As you can I couldn't match the sort from the IDs array. So is there an elegant way to achieve what I need? Thanks

Comment: You sort only on the "id" property. What are the other properties that are supposed to differentiate them? Compare them with `firstIndex(where:)` instead of `index(of:)`.

Comment: There is also a placeId property so the combination of both ids makes them unique.

Comment: Then use this one too to compare. You need to compare on a "unicity", either it's computed between multiple properties, (what about adding a lazy var to construct it?, returning a tuple `(id, placeId)`).

Comment: So let's say I put a combination of both - (id, placeId) tuple in the first array. How would I compare the models then in order to sort them?

Comment: Why not just compare the ids directly? Isn't the `idsArray` sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this for the "playground"):

```
struct Model {
    let id: String
    let placeId: String

    init(id: String, placeId: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.placeId = placeId
    }
}

extension Model {
    static func all() -> [Model] {
        let ids = ["ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl",
                   "n50cavoOJeRkjoRj11j3",
                   "TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7",
                   "TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7",
                   "TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7",
                   "ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl",
                   "mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b",
                   "TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7",
                   "Gc5lnHAKWm1OyeMkA9e7",
                   "n50cavoOJeRkjoRj11j3",
                   "mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b",
                   "mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b",
                   "ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl",
                   "X9WyrvEE253keNdlbVZc",
                   "ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl"]
        var models: [Model] = []
        for (index, anId) in ids.enumerated() {
            let aModel = Model(id: anId, placeId: String(index))
            models.append(aModel)
        }
        return models
    }
}
```

Then, I did this:

```
let initialModels = Model.all()
let shuffled = initialModels.shuffled()
print("shuffled:\n\(shuffled)")
```

So, `shuffled` is in wrong "order".

The issue with your current sort, is that `id` is not unique. You need to sort on a unique id, either computed, using compare on multiple properties, etc. Else, you can't tell which one is it between the multiple occurrences found, which according to you is the combination of `id` and `placeId` properties.

```
let initialValues: [(String, String)] = initialModels.map({ ($0.id, $0.placeId) })
```

In order for you to have:

```
func sort(by idsAndPlaceId: [(String, String)]) -> [Model]
```

Then, because I didn't want to use a `self`, etc, but that could be adaptable:

```
let resorted = shuffled.sorted { (model1, model2) -> Bool in
    let model1Index = initialValues.firstIndex(where: { (id, placeId) -> Bool in
        return id == model1.id && placeId == model1.placeId
    })
    let model2Index = initialValues.firstIndex(where: { (id, placeId) -> Bool in
        return id == model2.id && placeId == model2.placeId
    })
    return model1Index ?? 0 < model2Index ?? 0
}
print("resorted:\n\(resorted)")
```

Output:

```
$>shuffled:
[Model(id: "ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl", placeId: "0"), 
Model(id: "n50cavoOJeRkjoRj11j3", placeId: "1"), 
Model(id: "mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b", placeId: "10"), 
Model(id: "ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl", placeId: "5"),
Model(id: "X9WyrvEE253keNdlbVZc", placeId: "13"), 
Model(id: "n50cavoOJeRkjoRj11j3", placeId: "9"), 
Model(id: "ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl", placeId: "12"), 
Model(id: "TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7", placeId: "4"), 
Model(id: "mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b", placeId: "11"), 
Model(id: "Gc5lnHAKWm1OyeMkA9e7", placeId: "8"), 
Model(id: "TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7", placeId: "3"), 
Model(id: "ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl", placeId: "14"), 
Model(id: "TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7", placeId: "2"), 
Model(id: "TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7", placeId: "7"), 
Model(id: "mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b", placeId: "6")]
$>resorted:
[Model(id: "ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl", placeId: "0"), 
Model(id: "n50cavoOJeRkjoRj11j3", placeId: "1"), 
Model(id: "TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7", placeId: "2"), 
Model(id: "TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7", placeId: "3"), 
Model(id: "TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7", placeId: "4"), 
Model(id: "ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl", placeId: "5"), 
Model(id: "mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b", placeId: "6"), 
Model(id: "TE9ubEqV0tw0Hf4h8tk7", placeId: "7"), 
Model(id: "Gc5lnHAKWm1OyeMkA9e7", placeId: "8"), 
Model(id: "n50cavoOJeRkjoRj11j3", placeId: "9"), 
Model(id: "mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b", placeId: "10"), 
Model(id: "mkCs25zSf3J8QTvpS81b", placeId: "11"),
Model(id: "ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl", placeId: "12"), 
Model(id: "X9WyrvEE253keNdlbVZc", placeId: "13"), 
Model(id: "ITCAw554sCHlN3A6q7Yl", placeId: "14")]
```